# Firebase - Cloud Functions: enumerate [Object Object]

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I would like to enumerate the members object from the below structure.
I do not have prior experience in node.js, I have tried the following code and it doesn't seem to work.

[image: Structure]

```js
exports.sendVaultUnlockedPush = functions.database.ref('/Vaults/{id}/action').onUpdate(event => {
    let status = event.data.val();
    if (status == 'lock') {
        var db = admin.database();
        var vaultRef = db.ref("/Vaults/" + event.params.id);
        vaultRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            var hasMembers = snapshot.child('members');
            if (hasMembers) {
                var memberRef = db.ref("Vaults/" + event.params.id + "/members");
                memberRef.once('value').then(function(memberSnapshot) {
                    memberSnapshot.forEach(function(element) {
                        console(element.key + " - " + element.val());
                    }, this);
                });
            }
        });
    }
})
```

It throws the following error:

`Error: Firebase.DataSnapshot.forEach failed: Was called with 2 arguments. Expects no more than 1.
    at Error (native)
    at z (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:42:1666)
    at T.forEach (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:114:179)
    at /user_code/index.js:34:36
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)`

I would just like it to return the value of 'members' node. And I have no clue to do the same.
Any help is much appreciated in getting this sorted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) **forEach** takes only one parameter:

[image]

This should work:

```
var values;
memberSnapshot.forEach(function(element) {
    console(element.key);
    values = element.val();
    for (var val in values) {
        if (values.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
            console(val, values[val]);
        }
    }
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: That means it can only iterate `{x, y, z}` but not `{{x: y}, {x, y}}`
Can you let know, what should I use to iterate with two parameters?

Comment: @Nina I don't understand. **forEach** will iterate through each key. You can iterate through each element.val() with a for loop.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. Do I just update the `function(element)` to `function(element.val())`? 
Sorry!!! I am from iOS background, I just started node.js few days back for sending push notifications from firebase cloud.